# Delete and Create Partition in Mac Lion

Tags: mac, partitioning

I have Mac Mini 3 volumes.

1. Mac Lion
2. mac Data
3. Mac entertain

I want to delete the "Mac Data" and create a new partition in following order

1. Mac Lion
2. Mac entertain
3. NEW PARTITION

How to do it?

Comment: Don't. If it's possible, it's still dangerous and you can lose all your data. So just delete Data and entertain, and restore the latter from backup.

Answer (score 1):

To repartition a drive on MacOS, just use Disk Utility. It's in the Utilities folder inside your Applications folder. [Here's a simple tutorial on the subject](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/26/partition-hard-drive-mac-os-x/).

However, it sounds like you actually just want to delete all the information on Mac Data and change its name, which you can do from the finder. There's no reason to delete the partition unless you want to change its size or use a different filesystem.

Can you say more about the "order" you want? I don't think disk partitions have any natural "order" that's meaningful from a user's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Open Disk Utility (under Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility) and select your physical drive in the left pane. Then, select the partitions tab, click the partition you no longer want, and click the little minus symbol in the bottom left. Then click the plus symbol to make a new one.